# "GPG error: Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG"

Tags: apt, gnupg

I ran this command in the Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Updating ends with the following error report:

```
W: A error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>

W: GPG error: http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 4C1CBC1B69B0E2F4 Launchpad PPA for Jonathan French
W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/precise/Release
```

What does this mean and why is it happening?

Comment: I saw similar issue when I first installed the 12.04. After that I changed the "Software Sources" from the software manager from India to another server. Now I am not seeing this issue. If you are using India server, change it and let us know.

Comment: Thanx Abhijeet. I am an Indian but staying here in Qatar.I changed server to Saudi Arabia.But same result.

Comment: For myself, I had a PPA in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` that no longer existed and so this error was coming up. I had to remove that (actually, replace it with an updated repo for `ffmpeg` that I needed) and then `sudo apt-get update` worked just fine.

Comment: Because of low reputation, I can only comment. I solved the issue using the following command: `apt-key adv --fetch-keys 'https://packages.sury.org/php/apt.gpg' > /dev/null 2>&1`
Source: https://forum.hestiacp.com/t/apt-upgrade-failed-gpg-error-packages-sury-org/1920/8

Answer (score 130):

This message is displaying because the gpg key for that repository is missing in your apt-key database.

To import the key, open a terminal and enter these commands

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 16126D3A3E5C1192
```

pgp keys are mostly distributed in several keystore. Ubuntu related keys are usually found in `keyserver.ubuntu.com`. But if that fails you can use alternatives. Like -

```
gpg --keyserver hkp://subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys 16126D3A3E5C1192
```

You must replace the alphanumeric part, with the specific key. **Make sure the key is one you trust**. Any repository with this key, would be able to install any package without warning.

You would see the following output if the above is successful

```
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1
```

Then run this command:

```
gpg --export --armor 16126D3A3E5C1192 | sudo apt-key add -
```

**Note the `-` sign after `add`.**

Then `sudo apt-get update`, you will have no such messages after this.

Comment: Hi@anwar where/how do i get the key that i trust?

Comment: @MinnieShi The key is present in the error message itself
`The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 16126D3A3E5C1192 `

Comment: Note that the `apt-key add` command should return "OK".

Comment: Great, should be the accepted answer! Thanks.

Comment: I get this after the gpg --export, and it still fails with apt, any advice pls?: gpg: WARNING: unsafe ownership on homedir '/home/abc/.gnupg'; OK

Comment: the keyserver is currently hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 34):

I ran into this issue an older Ubuntu 16.04 box. My keys weren't expired so I wasn't really sure why I was getting the error. I tried SirCharlo's method but I still got the same errors. Being this particular error is coming from the 'Ubuntu Extras Archive Automatic Signing Key' I decided to refresh my keys. After doing that everything worked fine. Not sure if it was a combination of both method's but if SirCharlo's method doesn't work, run this command:

```
apt-key adv --refresh-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com
```

Comment: This works perfectly and looks safe. Thanks.

Comment: This should be the choosen answer!

Comment: This worked for me where not of the other answers worked. Using Ubuntu16.04 Xenial in a docker

Comment: Agreed. This feels a lot better to execute (and worked), thank you.

Answer (score 17):

You can try my script to automatically receive all GPG keys for PPAs you use: [smartupdate.sh](https://bitbucket.org/maaaks/mscripts/src/794bf751497987802a31e6466a99995efc17f213/smartupdate.sh?at=master).

It will launch `apt-get update`, then find all GPG errors and receive keys for found GPG signatures. In your case, it will just launch

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 4C1CBC1B69B0E2F4
```

but when you add a few unsigned PPAs, it becomes boring to add GPG keys manually. :)

Comment: other answers doesn't work  for me except this

Comment: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/7866 Good discussion here about this type of solution for expired keys.

Answer (score 7):

As [131](https://askubuntu.com/users/471847/131) suggested [in a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131601/gpg-error-release-the-following-signatures-were-invalid-badsig/1205537#comment1021247_181351) in [a now deleted answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/181351/618353), do it this way:

1. First clean things up:

   ```
   sudo apt-get clean
   ```
2. Optional step to save a backup and also preserve the ownership of `lists`:

   ```
   sudo cp -a /var/lib/apt/lists /tmp
   sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
   ```
3. Then rebuild the package list:

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```

---

#### NOTE

The following were suggested in [a highly upvoted answer that is now deleted](https://askubuntu.com/a/131621/618353):

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists /tmp
sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
```

This was not good advice because the `mv` and `mkdir` here create a new problem: `lists` is no longer owned by `_apt`. This means you'll now get this new `apt` warning:

```
W: Download is performed unsandboxed...
```

You need to preserve the existing ownership and permissions of the `lists` folder.

Comment: also you most likely free some space in ubuntu before trying to run any further command like apt update

Answer (score 6):

I got a similar error. But instead of `BADSIG` I got `KEYEXPIRED` for the PostgreSQL repo:

```
W: A error occurred during the signature verification.
  The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.
  GPG error: http://apt.postgresql.org precise-pgdg Release:
  The following signatures were invalid: KEYEXPIRED 1381654177
```

The solution is perfectly described [here](https://medium.com/@jaredowenbeck/please-update-your-pgdg-apt-key-eb46ee4e931a) but this is what I did to solve it:

```
$ sudo apt-key list | grep -B1 PostgreSQL
$ sudo apt-key del ACCC4CF8
$ wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

And now `$ sudo apt-get update` will work perfectly!

Answer (score 3):

I got quite similar error (on Debian 10):

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. 
GPG error: http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian buster InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: 
NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29

W: Failed to fetch http://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/dists/buster/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29

The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 467B942D3A79BD29
```

You can add the unavailable key and try again. In this my case the unavailable key is `467B942D3A79BD29`

So, key adding command will be `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 467B942D3A79BD29`

That solved my problem and `sudo apt update` fired like a charm.

Solution source: https://docs.mideye.se/5.6.6/installation/debian10/

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This tip (from [actionparsnip](https://launchpad.net/~andrew-woodhead666)) worked for me:

> Try:
>
> ```
> sudo fuser -vvv /var/lib/dpkg/lock
> sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/lock
> sudo cp -arf /var/lib/dpkg /var/lib/dpkg.backup
> sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/status-old /var/lib/dpkg/status
> sudo cp /var/lib/dpkg/available-old /var/lib/dpkg/available
> sudo rm -rf /var/lib/dpkg/updates/*
> sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists
> sudo rm /var/cache/apt/*.bin
> sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists
> sudo mkdir /var/lib/apt/lists/partial
> LANG=C;sudo apt-get clean
> LANG=C;sudo apt-get autoclean
> LANG=C;sudo apt-get --purge autoremove
> LANG=C;sudo apt-get update -o APT::Cache-Limit=25165824
> sudo dpkg --clear-avail
> sudo dpkg --configure -a
> LANG=C;sudo apt-get -f install
> LANG=C;sudo apt-get --fix-missing install
> LANG=C;sudo apt-get update -o APT::Cache-Limit=25165824 && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
> ```

Found in:
https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/update-manager/+question/194077

Answer (score 1):

This could be due to a caching issue of a HTTP proxy. If you have one of those somewhere along the route like me, you can run `apt` and circumvent the cache temporarily:

```sh
sudo apt-get update -o Acquire::http::No-Cache=True
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `launchpad-getkeys` to fix this.
Open a terminal and enter:

```
sudo apt-get install launchpad-getkeys
sudo launchpad-getkeys
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get update
```