# Why am I getting BADSIG error 13.04 / untrusted packages error in software manager

Tags: apt, updates, software-center

I am trying to update using sudo apt-get update.

receiving BADSIG error.

```
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg [933 B]
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring Release.gpg                                
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release.gpg
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release.gpg [933 B]
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring Release                                    
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security Release                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release.gpg          
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release                      
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Sources                    
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release                                
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages               
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates Release [40.8 kB]  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Sources              
Hit http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages                         
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Sources
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main amd64 Packages             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports Release             
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources/DiffIndex                 
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted amd64 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Sources/DiffIndex  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe amd64 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources/DiffIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Sources/DiffIndex  
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main i386 Packages     
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted i386 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe i386 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse amd64 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse i386 Packages
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages/DiffIndex
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en
Get:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Sources [14.0 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Sources [14 B]
Get:6 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Sources [9,167 B]
Get:7 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Sources [697 B]
Get:8 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main amd64 Packages [42.5 kB]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/main Translation-en_US
Get:9 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [14 B]
Get:10 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe amd64 Packages [29.6 kB]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com raring-security/universe Translation-en_US
Get:11 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [1,164 B]
Get:12 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main i386 Packages [42.0 kB]
Get:13 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted i386 Packages [14 B]
Get:14 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe i386 Packages [29.9 kB]
Get:15 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse i386 Packages [1,389 B]
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en            
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en        
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Sources                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Sources           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Sources             
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Sources           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main amd64 Packages          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted amd64 Packages    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe amd64 Packages      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse amd64 Packages    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main i386 Packages           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted i386 Packages     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe i386 Packages       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse i386 Packages     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-en          
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-en    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-en    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-en      
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Sources                           
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Sources                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Sources                       
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Sources                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main amd64 Packages                    
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted amd64 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe amd64 Packages                
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse amd64 Packages              
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main i386 Packages                     
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted i386 Packages               
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe i386 Packages                 
Hit http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse i386 Packages               
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/main Translation-en_US                 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/multiverse Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/restricted Translation-en_US           
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring/universe Translation-en_US             
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/main Translation-en_US         
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US   
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/restricted Translation-en_US   
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-updates/universe Translation-en_US     
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/main Translation-en_US       
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/multiverse Translation-en_US 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/restricted Translation-en_US 
Ign http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring-backports/universe Translation-en_US   
Fetched 213 kB in 17s (12.4 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://us.archive.ubuntu.com raring Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5 Ubuntu Archive Automatic Signing Key <ftpmaster@ubuntu.com>
```

How do I fix this?

Also getting installation errors about installing untrusted packages in ubuntu software center.

"Requires installation of untrusted packages"

```
   libgconf2-4 libxss1
```

This occurs when installing ANY application. different errors per app.

Never had this problem in Ubuntu until now. I'm about ready to leave and go back to Deb, but I like the look and feel of Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["GPG error: Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131601/gpg-error-release-the-following-signatures-were-invalid-badsig) and [How do I deal with “unauthenticated sources” errors in the Software Center?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/85641/how-do-i-deal-with-unauthenticated-sources-errors-in-the-software-center)

Answer (score 1):

Try all this first (as root of course):

```
# apt-get install -f
# dpkg --configure -a
# apt-get --fix-broken install
# apt-get --fix-missing install
```

If that doesn't work, try to install `aptitude`.

```
# apt-get install aptitude
```

And run

```
# aptitude update
# aptitude upgrade
```

Comment: This did not work, instead it crashed my pc. Instead I just tried re-installing the whole thing. Again did not work. 

With this I tried downloading from another source (even though the SHA and Checksum were fine) and burned again on low speed, now working fine. I wish I could figure out what happened...

Just a shot in the dark, but I checked my packets on my router, and they showed that I was losing packets when initially installing and downloading initial packages, would this be why the problems were prevalent?

Comment: @Lord_Rahl That could be the problem. I see no reason those commands would have screwed anything up; they are standard maintenance commands for broken packages and not dangerous in any way that I know of.