# Ubuntu 12.04 update nightmare and grub tiny problem

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager

I had some problems with the updates lately. It started with the update manager refusing to update because it requires installation of untrusted packages. I used : sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade and there were errors as well and said that 0 installed or updated or removed. Then after some time, ubuntu showed a red circle in the top bar saying that there might be dependencies that are unmet. I used sudo apt-get update and then sudo apt-get ugrade, strangely it worked but after that update manager now shows me there are some updates and when I try to update it says that some packages require installation of untrusted packages, again. ran the update and upgrade command, non were installed or updated. what shall I do now?

One more thing, after the last update, grub was updated I think and it now shows two entries for windows 7 ( dual booting ) one of them on sda1 and the other on sdb1 .. windows 7 boots normally from sda1, same as before. How can I remove the other entry.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/60ebf5trdfc0mjr/Screenshot%20from%202014-08-16%2012%3A54%3A56.png

that is the output of the 
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade now

Comment: try looking here http://askubuntu.com/questions/131601/how-to-overcome-signature-verification-error