# sudo apt-get update error

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, updates, update-manager

```
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. 

    The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used.

    GPG error: http://extras.ubuntu.com trusty Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: 

NO_PUBKEY 16126D3A3E5C1192

            W: Failed to fetch http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release
```

So can any one please give me the right key for this one? , i google it but i didnt find a related thing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following command to add missin gpg keys `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 16126D3A3E5C1192` then `sudo apt-get update`. This will fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this once, a while ago.

What you could do is clean up every cache from apt, by following:

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo mv /var/lib/apt/lists /tmp
sudo apt-get update
```

(Command-stack from ["GPG error: Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131601/gpg-error-release-the-following-signatures-were-invalid-badsig), where I found the answer when I had the issue)