# BADSIG 40976EAF437D05B5

Tags: 14.04, apt, package-management, updates

With lots of study in forums answered to the title, I am not able to solve. Please help !!!!

I am getting this when I run update via apt-get update every time.

I tried

```
sudo -i
apt-get clean
cd /var/lib/apt
mv lists lists.old
mkdir -p lists/partial
apt-get clean
apt-get update
```

The code does not work even after performing reboot

Also, I tried importing key

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5 and shows gpg unprocessed: 1

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
Release:        14.04
Codename:       trusty
```

Comment: Have you tried http://askubuntu.com/a/136838/158442 with the key in the error?

Comment: runned: sudo gpg --keyserver hkp://subkeys.pgp.net --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5  and got gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               unprocessed: 1

Comment: @ThomasW. gpg: no ultimately trusted keys found
gpg: Total number processed: 1
gpg:               imported: 1

Comment: none of the link worked :(