# How to install postgresql 9.1 on ubuntu 12.04 by adding repository?

Tags: 12.04, repository, postgresql

I installed postgresql using

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql-9.1 postgresql-9.1-contrib postgresql-9.1-postgis
```

then due to some reasons I need to uninstall postgresql from my system.
And uninstalled using:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql stop
sudo apt-get --purge remove postgresql\*
sudo rm -r /etc/postgresql/
sudo rm -r /etc/postgresql-common/
sudo rm -r /var/lib/postgresql/
userdel -r postgres
sudo userdel -r postgres
sudo groupdel postgres
```

Now I want to install the same version again, but there is no repository found. How could I add repo & install?

**cat /etc/apt/sources.list** gives:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20130213)]/ precise main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise universe
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise multiverse
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-backports main restricted universe multiverse

# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main restricted
# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security universe
# deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu precise partner

## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by third-party
## developers who want to ship their latest software.
# deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main
# deb http://qgis.org/debian precise main
# deb-src http://qgis.org/debian precise main
deb http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-proposed restricted main multiverse universe
```

And **apt-cache policy postgresql** gives:

```
N: Unable to locate package postgresql
```

**sudo apt-get update**:

```
Get:1 http://archive.canonical.com precise Release.gpg [2,839 B]
Get:2 http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [2,829 B]                                                    
Get:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise Release.gpg [2,839 B]                                                
Get:4 http://archive.canonical.com precise Release [2,835 B]                                                    
Get:5 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-updates Release.gpg [2,847 B]                                        
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-backports Release.gpg [2,849 B]                                      
Get:7 http://extras.ubuntu.com precise Release [2,825 B]                                                        
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg [2,856 B]                                                    
Get:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg [2,865 B]                                                    
Get:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net precise Release.gpg [2,848 B]                                                   
Get:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com precise-proposed Release.gpg [2,848 B]                                      
Ign http://archive.canonical.com precise Release                                                                
E: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com precise Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 1 NODATA 2
```

Comment: What is the output of `uname -a` ?

Comment: @GAD3R gets  `Linux user-desktop 3.5.0-23-generic #35~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 25 17:15:33 UTC 2013 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux`

Comment: Ubuntu 12.04.5 will lose support and become off topic here in a month. However you're not using the kernel shipped with Ubuntu 12.04.5 but something older. Please upgrade to Ubuntu 12.04.5 or any other [supported release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#Current).

Comment: It appears you have the right repositories with `postgresql` and `postgresql-9.1` enabled. Does `sudo apt-get update` run successfully or does it print warning or error messages?

Comment: @DavidFoerster getting GPG Error   , Updated in the question

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["GPG error: Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/131601/gpg-error-release-the-following-signatures-were-invalid-badsig)

Comment: Also `deb http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise main` should be unnecessary since you already receive the `precise/main` repository from `in.archive.ubuntu.com` earlier in the repository list.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Got NODATA issue: 'NODATA' (does the network require authentication?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/474549/got-nodata-issue-nodata-does-the-network-require-authentication)

Answer (score -1):

You can use the PostgreSQL Apt Repository. The PostgreSQL apt repository supports LTS versions of Ubuntu (12.04, 14.04 and 16.04) on amd64 and i386 architectures. To use the apt repository

1. Create the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list`, and add a line for the repository:

   ```
   deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ precise-pgdg main
   ```
2. Import the repository signing key, and update the package lists:

   ```
   wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

Comment: there is still  **GPG error**  on  **sudo apt-get update**.  Something is wrong in my system..